# Problem using Nintegrate and NDsolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, function-construction

I am going to use `Nintegrate` to integrate the result of `NDsolve` and also a `Table`. How I can do this? My code is:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

yy = 10^-4;
rr = 0.999;
xx = 10^-15;
zz = 10^-4;
mm = 10^-4;

ic = -17.5

s = NDSolve[{D[y[t], 
     t] == (3 y[t])/5 - (12 m[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (2 r[t] y[t])/
      5 - (6 x[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (3 y[t]^2)/5 + (7 y[t] z[t])/
      5 - (y[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
   D[r[t], t] == -((2 r[t])/5) - (12 m[t]^2 r[t])/5 + (2 r[t]^2)/
      5 - (6 r[t] x[t]^2)/5 + (3 r[t] y[t])/5 + (7 r[t] z[t])/
      5 - (r[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
   D[x[t], t] == (9 x[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 x[t])/5 + (r[t] x[t])/
      5 - (3 x[t]^3)/5 + (3 x[t] y[t])/10 + (x[t] z[t])/
      5 - (x[t] z[t]^2)/20, 
   D[z[t], t] == 
    12/5 + (12 m[t]^2)/5 - (12 r[t])/5 - (24 x[t]^2)/5 - (18 y[t])/
      5 - (18 z[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (r[t] z[t])/
      5 - (3 x[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (3 y[t] z[t])/10 + (13 z[t]^2)/10 - 
     z[t]^3/20, 
   D[m[t], t] == -2 Sqrt[3] - (6 m[t])/5 - 
     2 Sqrt[3] m[t]^2 - (6 m[t]^3)/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] r[t] + (m[t] r[t])/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] x[t]^2 - (3 m[t] x[t]^2)/5 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] y[t] + (3 m[t] y[t])/10 + 
     2 Sqrt[3] z[t] + (6 m[t] z[t])/5 - 
     z[t]^2/(4 Sqrt[3]) - (m[t] z[t]^2)/20, x[ic] == xx, y[ic] == yy, 
   m[ic] == mm, z[ic] == zz, r[ic] == rr}, {x, y, z, m, r}, {t, ic, 
   10}]
```

I use the result to find

```
H = Table[
  Exp[NIntegrate[z[t]/5 +  (z[t]^2)/20 /. 
     First@s, {t, 0, i}]], {i, -17.5, 10, 0.2}]
```

Now I am going to compute:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-t] x[t]^2 (H)^-1 , {t, 0, -7}]
```

but this does not work. In fact I dont know how to call H and x[t] together?

Comment: Sara, it doesn't make much sense to me to multiply your integrand by a table of numbers. Can you show us what mathematical expression yo are trying to reproduce?

Comment: Did you forget a `/. First@s` in your last `NIntegrate`?  Is `H` supposed to represent the interpolation of the table?

Comment: @MarcoB, In fact, this is a physical expression and I compute different parts with mathematica. The last step is integrating these quantities which originate from different parts. In other words, I dont know how to first, behave H as a function to be integrated beside `x[t]` and second how to gather `H` and `x[t]` with the analytical function `Exp[t]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, because of the existence of `H`, using `/. First@s` does not work. In fact I tried different type of writing my purpose and I couldn`t get result.

Comment: @sara [This seemed to work for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt39o.png). (I changed the step size in `Table` to speed up my test. It still took about 2.5 sec., so with a step size of `0.2`, it should take 25 sec or so, on my machine.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, would you let me know what is your exact command (regardless of stepsize)? It does not work for me! and about `H`, yes, I asked it to behave as a function.

Comment: Can you see it the image linked to "This seemed to work for me"? -- It was `NIntegrate[Exp[-t] x[t]^2 (H)^-1 /. First@s, {t, 0, -7}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2, It seems I was not specific enough, sorry, I want to first make a function out of `H` then integrate the expression so that the result is a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this gives what you want:  We construct the integral inside the definition of `H` by adding another ODE to the `NDSolve` system, which I called `logH`.  This in fact calculates the integral from `ic`, not from `0`.  So to define `H` we need to subtract `logH[0]` from `logH[t]` before exponentiating.  This should be a much more accurate (and faster) way of computing `H` than interpolating a table.

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, m, r, logH, t];

yy = 10^-4;
rr = 0.999;
xx = 10^-15;
zz = 10^-4;
mm = 10^-4;

ic = -17.5;

s = NDSolve[{D[y[t], 
      t] == (3 y[t])/5 - (12 m[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (2 r[t] y[t])/
       5 - (6 x[t]^2 y[t])/5 + (3 y[t]^2)/5 + (7 y[t] z[t])/
       5 - (y[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
    D[r[t], t] == -((2 r[t])/5) - (12 m[t]^2 r[t])/5 + (2 r[t]^2)/
       5 - (6 r[t] x[t]^2)/5 + (3 r[t] y[t])/5 + (7 r[t] z[t])/
       5 - (r[t] z[t]^2)/10, 
    D[x[t], t] == (9 x[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 x[t])/5 + (r[t] x[t])/
       5 - (3 x[t]^3)/5 + (3 x[t] y[t])/10 + (x[t] z[t])/
       5 - (x[t] z[t]^2)/20, 
    D[z[t], t] == 
     12/5 + (12 m[t]^2)/5 - (12 r[t])/5 - (24 x[t]^2)/5 - (18 y[t])/
       5 - (18 z[t])/5 - (6 m[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (r[t] z[t])/
       5 - (3 x[t]^2 z[t])/5 + (3 y[t] z[t])/10 + (13 z[t]^2)/10 - 
      z[t]^3/20, 
    D[m[t], t] == -2 Sqrt[3] - (6 m[t])/5 - 
      2 Sqrt[3] m[t]^2 - (6 m[t]^3)/5 + 
      2 Sqrt[3] r[t] + (m[t] r[t])/5 + 
      2 Sqrt[3] x[t]^2 - (3 m[t] x[t]^2)/5 + 
      2 Sqrt[3] y[t] + (3 m[t] y[t])/10 + 
      2 Sqrt[3] z[t] + (6 m[t] z[t])/5 - 
      z[t]^2/(4 Sqrt[3]) - (m[t] z[t]^2)/20, x[ic] == xx, y[ic] == yy,
     m[ic] == mm, z[ic] == zz, r[ic] == rr,
    (* add this line *)
    logH'[t] == z[t]/5 + (z[t]^2)/20, logH[ic] == 0
    },
   {x, y, z, m, r, logH}, {t, ic, 10}];
```

Now construct `H` from `logH`.

```
ClearAll[H];
With[{logH = logH /. First@s},
  H[t_] := Exp[logH[t] - logH[0]]];

H[t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see an image of the plot of `logH` inside the `InterpolatingFunction` in the image above.

Finally, here is the integral:

```
NIntegrate[
 Evaluate[Exp[-t] x[t]^2 (H[t])^-1 /. First@s],
 {t, 0, -7}]
(*  -2.25183  *)
```

Comment: That`s precious. Thank you.. @Michael E2